# How to work by jQuery data table for reading data from another controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have UsersController that includes Login Method and there is AfterLogin method in NEWSController.
ActionResualt Login in UsersController:

```
 public ActionResult Login(Users U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (NEWSDBContext DB = new NEWSDBContext())
            {
                var v = DB.Userss.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(U.UserName) && a.PassWord.Equals(U.PassWord)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {

                    Session["LogedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();


                  //  var SessionUserID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LogedUserID"];
                    Session["LogedUserFullname"] = v.Name.ToString() + " " + v.Family.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin","NEWS");
                }


            }
        }

        return View(U);
    }
```

ActionResualt AfterLogin in NEWSController:

```
public ActionResult AfterLogin()
    {


        ViewBag.message = Session["LogedUserFullname"].ToString();
        int id = int.Parse(Session["LogedUserID"].ToString());
        var kh=from n in db.NEWSs where n.UserID.Equals(id) select n;
       // NEWS news = db.NEWSs.Find(id); 
        return View(kh.ToList());
    }
```

Now I want when click on Login Button display jQuery DataTable that include information of AfterLogin.

Comment: What is the specific problem? Question is very vague

Comment: I want fetch records from NEWS model by UserID But no load view page,using Ajax .@charlietfl